# ElasticSearch: Keyword Query Does not Work

Tags: elasticsearch, keyword-search

I have a problem with keyword query.

I want to filter categoryProperties by key and value.

key is"color" and value contains "mavi"

But it gives me document it contains key is "color" and value contains "Beyaz"

Do you have any idea why?

**REQUEST**
I'm querying for searchQuery.categoryProperties.key and searchQuery.categoryProperties.values.value in below.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "nested": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "should": [{
                                                "bool": {
                                                    "must_not": [{
                                                        "term": {
                                                            "searchQuery.categoryProperties.key": {
                                                                "value": "color"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "bool": {
                                                    "must": [{
                                                        "term": {
                                                            "searchQuery.categoryProperties.key": {
                                                                "value": "color"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "nested": {
                                                            "query": {
                                                                "term": {
                                                                    "searchQuery.categoryProperties.values.value": {
                                                                        "value": "Mavi"
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            "path": "searchQuery.categoryProperties.values"
                                                        }
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "path": "searchQuery.categoryProperties"
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "searchQuery"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my 
**RESPONSE**

```
{
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "favoritesearchsearchmodelindex_2",
            "_type": "favoritesearchsearchmodel",
            "_id": "76175",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                "searchQuery": {
                    "categoryProperties": [
                    {
                        "key": "color",
                        "values": [{
                            "value": "Beyaz"
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

And the mapping of my document:
**MAPPING**

```
{
    "favoritesearchsearchmodelindex_2": {
        "mappings": {
            "favoritesearchsearchmodel": {
                "properties": {
                    "searchQuery": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "categoryProperties": {
                                "type": "nested",
                                "properties": {
                                    "intValue": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "key": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    },
                                    "values": {
                                        "type": "nested",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "value": {
                                                "type": "keyword"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem. You can look at the real answer: [Elastic Discuss Forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/keyword-query-does-not-work/101687/4?u=ibrahim_ozgon)

According to Mark response, I changed my mapping.
**New Mapping**

```
{
    "favoritesearchsearchmodelindex_2": {
        "mappings": {
            "favoritesearchsearchmodel": {
                "properties": {
                    "searchQuery": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "categoryProperties": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "key": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    },
                                    "numberValue": {
                                        "type": "double"
                                    },
                                    "values": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "value": {
                                                "type": "keyword"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "keyList": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "value": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After changing mapping i realized that;
I'm searching for `searchQuery.categoryProperties.key` is not `color`. I have an array and if one of the key is not `color`its ok for search, but not for me.
I created a `keyList` array and put all grouped keys of `searchQuery.categoryProperties.key` to `keyList`object.
Now I'm searching for `keyList`first. It gives me the correct response. This resolved my problem.

**Here is the correct REQUEST**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "nested": {
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "filter": [{
                                "bool": {
                                    "should": [{
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must_not": [{
                                                "term": {
                                                    "searchQuery.keyList.value": {
                                                        "value": "color"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "bool": {
                                            "must": [{
                                                "term": {
                                                    "searchQuery.categoryProperties.key": {
                                                        "value": "color"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "term": {
                                                    "searchQuery.categoryProperties.values.value": {
                                                        "value": "Mavi"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "searchQuery"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```